# How to deserialize json array of objects into object with properties?

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization, .net-4.8, system.text.json

I am working with the following JSON string from api response:

```json
{
    "points": [{
            "name": "title",
            "value": "Test"
        }, {
            "name": "category",
            "value": null
        }, {
            "name": "created",
            "value": 1550743894373
        }, {
            "name": "version",
            "value": 1
    }]
}
```

the json-structure of the response is always the same, root-node "points" has 1 or more name-value pairs.

I have a class structure as follows for parsing and filling the json data

```cs
// can't use record, have to use class, i only have .NET Framework 4.8 available
public class Point
{
    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyViews
{
    [JsonPropertyName("points")]
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my code:

```cs
using RestSharp;

// create request for API
var request = new RestRequest("my-views");

// get response from API with deserialized json-data to my Points-object
var response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync<MyViews>(request);

// just example of getting simple data from object
Point response_point = response.Data.Points.first(); // get first object
string title;
// check if object is a title
if (response_point.Name == "title") {
    title = response_point.Value; // get value of title
}}

// my goal is:
// Point response_point = response.Data;
// title = response_point.title;
```

**My deserialization goal is to fill data in the following class structure:**

```cs
public class Point
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created { get; set; }
    public int? version { get; set; }    
}
```

I want to have only one "Point" object with all name-value pairs as properties (without List in MyViews class).

Is there a way to transform the data on deserialization process, or trigger a method on Points-object after deserialization complete?

I'm using `RestSharp-lib` with default serializer `System.Text.Json`.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I'm not attached to any library, I have free choice, the only restriction I have to stick to is .NET 4.8 Framework.

Comment: ```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Points>(yourjson);
```

Use it to deserialize it to your model.

Comment: It looks like it should be `[JsonPropertyName("data")]`. I don't see where "points" is coming from

Comment: I'm a little surprised you are using System.Text.Json in .NET 4.8.  What version of System.Text.Json are you using?  If you are not sure, in runtime you can do `Console.WriteLine("{0} version: {1}", typeof(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer).Namespace,  typeof(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer).Assembly.FullName);`

Comment: @Narish thanks for pointing JsonPropertyName, i fixed in my example above.

Comment: @dbc i downloaded fresh package (RestSharp and also System.Text.Json as separate package) from Nuget. output from runtime: `"System.Text.Json version:  System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"`

Comment: I was able to create a generic converter that automatically deserialized and re-serialized your `Point` class to JSON as a name/value pair array, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/tbXJ9T.  However, when I tried to use the same converter in .NET Framework 4.7, I got a compilation error *`'System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader' is obsolete: 'Types with embedded references are not supported in this version of your compiler.'`*, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/tbXJ9T.  It seems it may not be possible to write custom converters in .NET 4.x because ref structs like `Utf8JsonReader` are not supported.

Comment: Want that as an answer?

Comment: Honestly, I don't recommend using System.Text.Json in .NET Framework 4.x even if it is nominally possible because 1) Lack of C# language language for some features 2) Lack of MSFT attention and testing.  Stick with Json.NET in that version.  See [this documentation page](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html#newtonsoftjson-aka-json-net) for instructions on using Json.NET in RestSharp.

Comment: @dbc that's it! I think you have hit the point, thank you for the code example, this is exactly what I was looking for. and thanks for the hint with Json.NET, i will change to it.

Comment: @b166er Text.Json and Net 4.8  is the worst combination ever. Install Newtonsoft.Json and  the code will be much simplier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text.Json and Net 4.8 is the worst combination ever. Install Newtonsoft.Json and the code will be simpler.

```
using Newonsoft.Json;

var response = await client.ExecuteGetAsync(request);

var points = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["points"];

Point point = new Point();

foreach (var item in points)
{
    var val = item["value"];
    switch ((string)item["name"])
    {
        case "title": point.title = (string)val; break;
        case "category": point.category = (string)val; break;
        // case "created":point.created = (DateTime) val; break; //only you know what format is your date
        case "version": point.version = (int?)val; break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class which converts back and forth from a JSON string structure.

Here's a sample implementation that works on the .NET Framework 4.8.1

```
public T JsonToObject<T>(string p_Json)
{
    T returnValue;
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer;

    serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    returnValue = serializer.Deserialize<T>(p_Json);

    return returnValue;
}
```

and this is how you'd call it

```
object results;
results = JsonToObject<object>("your-json-string");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array instead of list:

```
public class Point
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public DateTime? created { get; set; }
    public int? version { get; set; }
}

public class MyViews
{
    [JsonPropertyName("points")]
    public Point[] Points { get; set; }   // <- an array of the Points
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
            ""points"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""title"",
                    ""value"": ""Test""
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""category"",
                    ""value"": null
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""created"",
                    ""value"": 1550743894373
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""version"",
                    ""value"": 1
                }
            ]
        }";

        MyViews myViews = new MyViews();
        // --> Here we deserialize the json to an array of Points
        myViews.Points = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Point[]>(json);  

        Console.WriteLine("Deserialized Points:");
        foreach (Point point in myViews.Points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Title: {point.title}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Category: {point.category}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Created: {point.created}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Version: {point.version}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        string serializedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myViews);
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized JSON:");
        Console.WriteLine(serializedJson);
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, i get array of Point objects (same number as name-value object as in json-result), but all properties (point.title, ..., point.version) of every Point-object is null.

Comment: For both newtonsoft and the std lib JSON library, `List<T>` and `T[]` are both valid for deserializing a JSON array. Yes you will save on some allocations when using an array, but if that isn't necessary there is no harm in using a list whatsoever